# call recorder doesn't saves recording

Tags: android

m new to android, was just trying to record the calls. After hanging up, recording should be saved but it's not there in storage. can somebody help me with it

```
public void startRecording() throws IOException {
    ditchRecord();
    File outFile=new File(OUTPUT_FILE);
    if(outFile.exists()){
        outFile.delete();
    }
    recorder= new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);
    recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
    recorder.prepare();
    recorder.start();

}

private void ditchRecord() {
    if(recorder!=null)
        recorder.release();
}
```

Comment: please check this http://www.truiton.com/2015/05/capture-record-android-screen-using-mediaprojection-apis/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioSource.html#VOICE_CALL),

> Capturing from VOICE_CALL source requires the CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT permission. This permission is reserved for use by system components and is not available to third-party applications.

Hence, it looks like what you're trying to do is not possible, unless your app is installed as a system app, which will only work on rooted devices.

Comment: However if its for personal use, a rooted phone can give system permissions to any app, you just have to install it correctly.

Comment: thanx tough, i've rooted mine but i was trying to make it work on other devices